# Docusign API sending envelop not showing in recipient's account

Tags: docusignapi

```
let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
                        email: 'jd@gmail.com',
                        name: 'John Doe',
                        recipientId: '1',
                        routingOrder: '1'});
```

I created a signer with this function, and the that recipient has a Docusign account, however, the notification only goes into his email, but not showing up in his Docusign account.

Are there anything I can do to make sure the envelop show up in his Docusign?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few things. One - the name as it appears on his DocuSign account must match exactly, so "John Doe" should be the name in the account.
Also, possible there are more than 1 user with jd@gmail.com so then again, the system won't know which account to add this to.
Finally, of course, must remember to ensure if it's the Developer Account (demo) then you also check that for the other user/account. Production and demo are different of course.

You could try to add a **userId** in the JSON and that is the GUID for this particular user in the system. That should make it easier for the system to match the user to the account.

Comment: Since I'm sending to specific person, I can just ask the userId of the signer, but where is he going to find his userId. He is just using a regular account, not a developer.

Comment: if you want you can do that programmatically if you Auth into the API with that account. The Admin can see the userIds of all the users in the system by going to the Settings tab. Let me check if a user can see their own userId if they are not admin.

Comment: I'm having developer account, and I found the userId for the account that I'm sending to, does these accounts have to be under same billing account? Or it could be just random account?

Comment: Okay, i think i did everything I can. Thanks for your answers, I think I'll have to ask Docusign directly.